# How to change image on listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem when i click to change image from listview: i just need to change image in row i click. and when i choose another image, this image i chosen become image normal. please help me!

MainActivity

```
public void songPicked(final View view) throws IOException {
        musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.playc);
        musicSrv.playSong();
        if (playbackPaused) {
            setController();
            playbackPaused = false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }
```

MyAdapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //map to song layout
        RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout) songInf.inflate
                (R.layout.song, parent, false);
        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        final ImageView imageView= (ImageView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);

        //get title and artist strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));


        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWGlN.jpg

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. You want the image to change once clicked, and then revert when you choose a different row? And the issue is that it stays the old image? Or is the other way around?

Comment: yes,i want the image to change once clicked, and then revert when you choose a different row? please help me?

Comment: How is songPicked called?

Comment: i make: class MusicService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener

Comment: function  songPicked called:                                              <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="songPicked"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>